# Get closest possible Date value from HBase table scan

Tags: hbase

I want to scan a table in HBase to retrieve the closest possible match to the rowkey by using a `scan`.

rowkey eg: `2017-11-22 10:20:30`

if I use a RowFilter like

```
scan 'mytable',{FILTER=>"(RowFilter(=,'regexstring:2017-11-22 10:20:30'))"}
```

I want it to return the closest possible row to this time.  So if the closest rowkey was `2017-11-22 09:00:00` this is the result return.

Currently with the above query it reurns 0 rows, as it does not match exactly.  Is this possible with `scan`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a suitable scan search for this:

```
scan 'mytable', {ENDROW => "2017-11-22 10:20", REVERSED => true, LIMIT => 1}
```